# What mechanisms could keep Universe at 0 energy?

Tags: cosmology, energy-conservation, space-expansion, universe

In my understanding is right, there is no obvious guarantee of the conservation of energy on the cosmological scale. The expansion of space-time causes the red-shift of radiation and therefore the loss of energy. On the other hand – it increases the distances between massive objects, which increases the gravitations energy binding these bodies.

On the other hand there are some clues that point to the idea of 0 energy Universe. If the energy is 0 energy (and it’s not by blind luck) there must exist some mechanism that guarantees the conservation of energy on a cosmological scale. In my understanding this should be some law that binds the expansion rate with radiation and mass (and probably other factors).

If my understanding is right, are there any proposals for such law? If I’m wrong, where am I making the mistake?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What makes you say the universe is at 0 energy? Furthermore, if it already is at 0 energy, why would it change? (since conservation of energy)

Comment: @Allure the OP is correct in the broad sense: the classical notion of energy conservation falls apart in general relativity, see e.g. https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2010/02/22/energy-is-not-conserved/ for a cogent explanation.

Comment: Nothing really makes *me* say it is at 0 energy. However the idea of 0 energy universe is a theory postulated by some physicists like Edward Tryon.

Comment: @KyleOman I still don't understand the question - if energy is not conserved it's not expected to stay at 0 energy (even if it starts at 0 energy). Or one could just change the definition of energy and say energy is conserved, which would guarantee energy stays at 0.